# Hiding asides in Ocotopress

Tags: css, jekyll

Anyone know of a way to remove or hide the asides panel for some pages in an Ocotopress site?

How about defaulting the aside to expanded (ie, shown at the bottom rather than the right hand side)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the yaml front matter you can force it to the bottom of the page with:

```
sidebar: collapse
```

If you want to disable it use:

```
sidebar: false
```

Comment: Should I put this in `_config.yml` in Main Config ? As in `description:
# sidebar: false
sidebar: collapse`. Collapse I can see but false does not do anything

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `sidebar: collapse` works in global _config.yml, but `sidebar: false` works on a per-page basis; you should enter sidebar: false in your article header. Otherwise consider editing/customizing layouts. (see source/_layouts and/or source/_includes/custom)