# Disable asides on a per-page basis in Octopress?

Tags: octopress

[Hiding asides in Ocotopress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714990/hiding-asides-in-ocotopress) seems to indicate how to do this on a site-wide basis, but I'd like to be able to have only specific pages collapse the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

To collapse the sidebar site-wide you add `sidebar:collapse` to `_config.yml`. To collapse the sidebar for a particular post or page, you add the same line to the YAML header for that post or page.